# How to write real integration test in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, tdd, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two questions, but let me start from the beginning. I have ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI and I'm looking for the most optimal way to end-to-end test my controllers (**I don't want to use `InMemory` provider**). I separated my tests in two sets: "Read-only" (`GET`) and "Read-write" (`POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`). For Read-only tests I want create brand new database (I use code-first migrations) once, and then tests all `GET` requests one by one. For Read-write requests, I want to create new database and drop it after the test.

This is what I've done so far:

```
public class TestFixture<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;

    public TestFixture()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<TStartup>();
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
        {
            conf.AddUserSecrets(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        });

        _server = new TestServer(builder);

        Client = _server.CreateClient();
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Client.Dispose();
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

... and the test:

```
public class TestControllerShould : IClassFixture<TestFixture<Startup>>
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public TestControllerShould(TestFixture<Startup> fixture)
    {
        Client = fixture.Client;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetHelloWorld()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "/test/");

        // Act
        var response = await Client.SendAsync(request);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Equal("Hello World!", content);
    }
}
```

I have two problems. First of all, I'm using `Startup` from main project (which is desired, because I want to test it after all) with production connection string, so that's one problem. Second problem, I would to create and drop database after each "write" test, which I can't from obvious reasons. So my questions are:

1. How can I use `Startup` class, but only change the database name to `"MyDatabaseName + Guid.NewGuid()"`?
2. Second question, how can I create and drop database (with unique name) before and after every test?

**PS.** I don't want to use `InMemory` provider. I also don't want to use transaction and rollback at the end of the test. I want to do real integration test.

Comment: What you're talking about is a systems test, *not* an integration test. Whether or not something ultimately makes it to a database server is not a function of your app code. EF Core has its own comprehensive suite of tests to ensure that. The point of the in memory database is to provide a mock to do integration testing quickly and easily. Introducing a real database actually invalidates your test, as it can now fail if there's a problem with your database instance, even if your code is 100% correct.

Comment: A valid test should fail only if there's actually a problem in the code. If that's not the case, you're just wasting your time.

Comment: @ChrisPratt shouldn't integration test mimic whatever you have in production? The problem with the inmemory database is that it's not postgresql, it's sqlserver. Are you saying that one code will work exactly the same for every database provider, including InMemory database?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, yes. You can safely assume that any included EF database provider works as it should, as it's going to have its own test suite. The whole point of EF as an abstraction is that you don't need to worry about the actual database backend. Otherwise, you'd have to have custom code for each database. Regardless, it's not a concern of an integration test. An integration test is testing that the components of *your* app work as they should, not that PostgreSQL can actually write a row.

Comment: There is value in testing the actual database connection, but that's a *systems test*, and it's an entirely different thing. You'd do that as part of a deployment in a release pipeline, for example, not every time you build your app or commit code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I got you. Should the system test be implemented inside my project? Along with integration and unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [latest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) for ASP.NET Core 3.1 correctly, we're now expected to use `WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>`.

You can override its `ConfigureWebHost` method to change configuration, dependencies, and so on. I recently did this by replacing a real database implementation with a Fake:

```
public class RestaurantApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptors = services
                .Where(d =>
                    d.ServiceType == typeof(IReservationsRepository))
                .ToList();
            foreach (var d in descriptors)
                services.Remove(d);

            services.AddSingleton<IReservationsRepository>(
                new FakeDatabase());
        });
    }
}
```

Instead of replacing the your SQL Server-based database implementation with a Fake, you could probably change its connection string as well.

You use the factory like this:

```
using var factory = new RestaurantApiFactory();
var client = factory.CreateClient();
```

It looks like you're using xUnit.net. If so, you can use its `BeforeAfterTestAttribute` to create and delete databases for each test.

Here's the way I usually do it:

```
public class UseDatabaseAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        using (var schemaStream = ReadSchema())
        using (var rdr = new StreamReader(schemaStream))
        {
            var schemaSql = rdr.ReadToEnd();

            var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
                ConnectionStrings.Reservations);
            builder.InitialCatalog = "Master";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                foreach (var sql in SeperateStatements(schemaSql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        base.Before(methodUnderTest);
    }

    private Stream ReadSchema()
    {
        return typeof(SqlReservationsProgramVisitor<>)
            .Assembly
            .GetManifestResourceStream(
                "Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.Sql.BookingDbSchema.sql");
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> SeperateStatements(string schemaSql)
    {
        return schemaSql.Split(
            new[] { "GO" },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        base.After(methodUnderTest);

        var dropCmd = @"
            IF EXISTS (SELECT name
                FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
                WHERE name = N'Booking')
            DROP DATABASE[Booking];";

        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
            ConnectionStrings.Reservations);
        builder.InitialCatalog = "Master";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(dropCmd, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it in use [here](https://github.com/ploeh/dependency-injection-revisited/blob/master/CSharp/BookingApi.SqlTests/SqlReservationsProgramVisitorTests.cs).